# Why hot reload and hot restart showing different results in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, build

I tried to implement API Calling in the code given below, but when I print the result and run the code, the output prints the same statement twice even when the function is called once by the FutureBuilder in build function.

But when I hot reload it, the print statement only show up once. Can anyone tell what I am missing here?

This is the Code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Practice extends StatefulWidget {
  const Practice({super.key});

  @override
  State<Practice> createState() => _PracticeState();
}

class _PracticeState extends State<Practice> {

  Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getData() async {
    final url = "https://dummyjson.com/products";

    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var body = res.body;

    print(body.runtimeType);

    var data = jsonDecode(body);

    print(data.runtimeType);

    return data;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
          builder: ( context, snapshot){
            return const Scaffold();
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output on Hot Restart.

```
flutter: String
flutter: _Map<String, dynamic>
flutter: String
flutter: _Map<String, dynamic>
```

This is the output on Hot Reload.

```
flutter: String
flutter: _Map<String, dynamic>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `build` method can run many times, not only twice. You should avoid using the `getData()` function directly in the build method.

Instead, set up a member variable in the state class, and set its value to your function once in `initState`. You can use this member variable to set the `future` parameter when constructing the `FutureBuilder`. This way it will run only once, because `initState` is called only once during a widget's life cycle.

This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) as well:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Try this code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Practice extends StatefulWidget {
  const Practice({super.key});

  @override
  State<Practice> createState() => _PracticeState();
}

class _PracticeState extends State<Practice> {
  // member variable to hold the future
  late final Future<Map<String,dynamic>> _getDataFuture;

  Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getData() async {
    final url = "https://dummyjson.com/products";

    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var body = res.body;

    print(body.runtimeType);

    var data = jsonDecode(body);

    print(data.runtimeType);

    return data;
  }

  // add this to init your future
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getDataFuture = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        // use the member variable here
        future: _getDataFuture,
        builder: ( context, snapshot){
          return const Scaffold();
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: if for any reason you do want to re-run the future, you can do this:

```
setState(() {
  _getDataFuture = getData();
});
```

**In this case it is important to remove the `final` modifier from the declaration of `_getDataFuture` otherwise you'll get an error when re-assigning its value!**